Ubuntu 24.04, Cannot access websites, connect: Network is Unreachable
When I ping 8.8.8.8 it returns connect: Network is unreachable.
ip route list returns nothing.
service.network.manager restart returns, Unit network.manager.service not found.

Maybe you need Internet. Is your computer connected to anything at all? Check you have an Ethernet cable. If you do, try connecting one end to the back of your computer and the other end to a router. Subscribe to Internet service from an Internet Service Provider (ISP). Maybe you need to use WiFi. We can't tell if you did any of these things unless you edit your question.

Are you using a supported Ubuntu release? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].

What is the output of ip a?

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.
